# How to reach complex parts of JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

This is my JSON response

```
{
error: false,
loggedin: null,
-data: {
    -homework: [
    -{
        +HomeworkSession: {},
        +elements: []
    },
    +{},
    {},
    {}
    ],
    +lessons: {},
    +date_span: {},
    +type: "parents"
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to reach **HomeworkSession**.
I fetched this JSON by putting it in NSData using this code:

```
_jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                  [NSURL URLWithString:@"my_url"]];
```

But I cannot go from there..whatever I do i get nil in response. 
ANy piece of code would be helpful!

Comment: Parse it hierarchically into objects.

Comment: Peel it like an onion.  One layer at a time, assign the result to a temp, NSLog it to see what you have, then peel the next layer.  (And especially with JSON trying to copy code from somewhere else hardly ever works -- it's gotta be designed to fit your particular data.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be something like this:-

```
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    NSDictionary * data = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSArray * homework = [data objectForKey:@"homework"];

    for(int i=0;i<homework.count;i++){
        NSDictionary * singleHomework = [homework objectAtIndex:i];

        NSDictionary *HomeworkSession = [singleHomework objectForKey:@"HomeworkSession"];
        NSArray *elements = [singleHomework objectForKey:@"elements"];

        NSLog(@"%@",HomeworkSession);
        NSLog(@"%@",elements);
    }
```

**Note**: The NSLog will display nil as HomeworkSession and elements are empty.